# Create attribute with type "select" but without options

Tags: magento, attributes

I try to create new attribute with type `select` in the installer. But I don't know whether it's possible to create such an attribute without setting any options. Here is my code:

```
  $installer = $this;

  $config = array(
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'input' => 'select',
    'label' => 'Theme',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'apply_to' => null,
    'searchable' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'option' => array(
        'values' => array()
    )   
 );

$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'custom_attr', $config);
```

Attribute is created but it has `text` type. Please help!

Comment: Elaborate "doesn't work", please.

Comment: Edited. Please look at.

Comment: Please check the  link -
[http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5977/how-to-create-drop-down-attributes-for-customer][1]


  [1]: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5977/how-to-create-drop-down-attributes-for-customer
Let me know if you have any query

Comment: Create `select` attribute without any option is a main problem. But in this link I see explain only creation attribute with option.